# Send Email from RCP Application

Tags: java, swt, jakarta-mail, rcp

I am working with rcp application. I am trying to send an email from my application when click on a button. But i got this error.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendHandshake(SMTPTransport.java:1840)
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:393)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:242)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:85)
    at com.twopiradian.infotech.mail.Mail.send(Mail.java:56)
    at com.twopiradian.infotech.GetPasswordOperation.execute(GetPasswordOperation.java:60)
    at net.sourceforge.sqlexplorer.dialogs.PasswordDialog$1$1.run(PasswordDialog.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
    at net.sourceforge.sqlexplorer.dialogs.PasswordDialog$1.handleEvent(PasswordDialog.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at net.sourceforge.sqlexplorer.sqlpanel.SQLExecution$2.run(SQLExecution.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at net.sourceforge.sqlexplorer.rcp.SQLExplorerApplication.start(SQLExplorerApplication.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

The property set that i have used are,

```
mail.smtp.user=usermail@gmail.com
mail.smtp.password=userpassword
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.debug=true
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
```

I am stuck with this error since one whole day, but i could not figure out how to solve it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Get rid of all the socket factory stuff](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) and follow the [Gmail example in the JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail).

Comment: Eclipse product has a problem for sending email if we use geronimo.javamail. Instead of it, i have use sun.javamail. It is working.